# QGIS qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "windows" in "" even

Tags: qgis, python

I run often Metshape software from QGIS app, however I recently encounter a problem.
I use this script:

```
import sys
import os
script_path = "D:/script.py"
commandline = '"C:/Program Files/Agisoft/Metashape Pro/metashape.exe"' + " -r " + script_path
timer_value = 10
os.system(commandline + " & timeout " + str(timer_value))
```

This script run perfectly with python 3.6 but in QGIS app, I have this error :

> qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "windows" in "" even though it was found.
> This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
> Available platform plugins are: direct2d, minimal, offscreen, windows.

Can anyone guess ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finaly, I solved my problem with this line :

```
os.environ['QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH'] = "C:/Program Files/Agisoft/Metashape Pro/plugins/platforms"
```